# Typescript: How Do You Define A Type at the End of a Nesting Structure of Unknown Depth?

Tags: typescript

I have an application that has i18n defined in config like so...

```
{
    message: {
        error: {
            en: "this is an error message",
            de: "das ist eine Fehlermeldung"
        }
    }
}
```

I currently have the types for this defined as...

```
type LocalizationObject = {
    [locale: string]: string;
};

type LocalizationPart = {
    [codePart: string]: LocalizationPart | LocalizationObject
}
```

The problem I have is that the nesting chain must always end with a `LocalizationObject`, but the depth of the nesting is unknown, could be 1 or 100 deep.

Is there a way to specify that the type of the last object must be `LocalizationObject`?